# Svelte 3: empty CSS file after build customComponent

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a strange behaviour at the svelte build process. I have a `customComponent` in Svelte.

```html
<script lang="typescript" src="./Map.ts">

</script>

<style lang="scss" src="./Map.scss">

</style>

<svelte:options tag="dbconnect-web-map" />
<template src="./Map.html" />
```

At the `Map.scss` there is only one rule to test which should be set the background yellow.

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Here is my `rollup.config.js` to build the component with `npm run build`

```js
...
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
  input: 'src/main-map.js',
  output: {
    format: 'iife',
    file: 'public/build/dbconnect-web-map.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
      // we'll extract any component CSS out into
      // a separate file - better for performance
      emitCss: true,
      css: (css) => {
        css.write('public/build/dbconnect-web-map.css');
      },
      customElement: true,
      preprocess: autoPreprocess({
        /* options */
      }),
    }),
...
```

The CSS file `dbconnect-web-map.css` is generated at `public/build/dbconnect-web-map.css` but the content of the file is empty. Only the advice to the `css.map` file is there.

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=dbconnect-web-map.css.map */
```

The `dbconnect-web-map.css.map` file looks fine I think, but I'm not sure.

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "dbconnect-web-map.css",
  "sources": [],
  "sourcesContent": [],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": ""
}
```

No clue why the one CSS rule with `body` is not included. Would be very nice when someone can help me. By the way, I use node v12.18.0 and npm v.6.14.4. I don't know if this is a problem but I want to put it here to test it on your own side.

Comment: Do you need: emitCss: true,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the list of custom elements specific differences / limitations at the end of the [corresponding docs section](https://svelte.dev/docs#Custom_element_API).

I think the relevant one for you is this one:

> Instead of being extracted out as a separate .css file, styles are inlined into the component as a JavaScript string

This one is also probably of interest:

> Styles are encapsulated, rather than merely scoped. This means that any non-component styles (such as you might have in a global.css file) will not apply to the custom element, including styles with the :global(...) modifier

Custom elements don't need CSS scoping, because they are rendered in shadow DOM, where their CSS is encapsulated *de facto*.

Also, the shadow DOM doesn't support having stylesheets in a reliable cross-browser way. Hence the first limitation I've quoted.

My personal impression from my experience with Svelte custom elements is that there are even more differences in behaviour with their standard counterparts than stated in the docs. I would avoid using them whenever I can. Maybe you should recheck why you want them and if you really want them before sinking too much time in making them work. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Nice to hear. Can you accept the answer, if it solved your problem? Welcome on SO, btw!